# Solving the emptyview & header view in listview

Tags: android, android-listview

I have a listview, in which I attach an emptyview ONLY when the adapter has no results.
I also attach before setting the adapter to the listview a HEADER view (used for LOADING...).

The scenario is ok for the first initialisation of the listview, in which I see the LOADING (header view) and when no results I see the empty view.

HOWEVER, the problem is when I try to reload it, the EMPTY view is still showing, the LOADING is not appearing.
I know for sure it is loaded correctly within the adapter.

What is the best way to handle both empty & loader views in the listview?

Thanks!

Comment: Without code, it is hard to predict..:)

Comment: Paste your code here.